# matlab: Getting correct indices for an array

Tags: matlab

I'm having an array and when I apply find(im), I get indices for non zero elements. But, I want indices for all elements of array irrespective whether it is zero or non zero.
Here is my array:

```
im =[94 122 99 101 111 101;
99 92 103 87 107 116;
93 109 113 84 86 106;
5 17 6 54 56 53;
13 11 5 56 44 50;
0 10 5 49 42 51];
```

when I apply find(im): I get indices: 35(Since the array contain 0 in it). But I need to get 36.

How do i do it?

Comment: What is the point of getting the indices of all the elements? Isn't that equivalent to getting the entire array?

Comment: true. but find() returns  vector containing the linear indices of each nonzero element in array im. But i need to get indices for each elements in array

Comment: Your indices for all elements in the array will be `1:numel(im)`. I still don't get why you would need to find all elements: they are right there in front of you. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Since you want the linear indices of all elements in the array, and you know the number of elements in the array, their indices will be:

```matlab
im = magic(5);
indices = 1:numel(im)
```

I.e. if you were to loop the array you would be looping all of the elements.